Meaning of "virō" in description of Lavinia
On p. 29 of Roma Aeterna by Hans Ørberg, book II of Lingua Latina Per Se Illustrata, is this passage from a simplified Latin, solūtīs versibus (prose) rendering of Book II of the Aeneid:

Faunō mortuō, Latīnus, fīlius eius, regnum accēpit. Huius fīlius in prīmā iuventūte periit; sōla in rēgiā erat fīlia, nōmine Lāvīnia, iam mātūra virō. Illam multī virī ē Latiō tōtāque Italiā petēbant, ante omnēs Turnus, rex Rutulōrum.

What does virō mean in this context? Is it a dative, meaning "from the perspective of"? So then the whole passage would mean (liberally translated):

When Faunus died, his son Latinus received the kingdom. His son died early in his youth; alone in the castle was his daughter, named Lavinia, already mature for a suitor. Many men from Latium and throughout Italy sought her, most notably Turnus, king of the Rutuli.

Is that right? "Mature enough for a man"? "Mature enough to be married"? "Mature by the standard used for men"? "Already on the old side to take a husband"?
(Please let me know if I've made any other errors in the rest of the translation, too.)

As the Lewis & Short entry for maturus notes under meaning II.A, a common construction is maturus + dat., which means "ripe/ready for X."
It gives examples such as:

maturus bello = old enough for war
vitulus templis maturus et arae = a calf old enough for sacrifice (literally: for temples and the altar)

In this case then, you're right: maturus viro literally means "old enough for a man/husband" but it sounds better in English to say, of marriageable age.
Virgil himself uses this same expression in Aeneid VII, along with a synonymous expression: nubilis plenis annis.

sola domum et tantas seruabat filia sedes
iam matura uiro, iam plenis nubilis annis.

You can also find this same expression in Gellius, Noctes Atticae 12.8:

P. Scipio filiam uirginem habens iam uiro maturam ibi tunc eodem in loco despondit eam Tiberio Graccho. . . .

Translation:

Publius Scipio, having a virgin daughter who was now of marriageable age betrothed her then and there, at the same place, to Tiberius Gracchus. . . .

See also Statius, Achilleis I.1: "virginitas matura toris" ("maidenhood that is ready for the marriage bed").

Similarly, viro can and often does simply mean "husband", as "man" can in English, муж once could in Russian.

Added that: you're right!

@cmw As muž/mąż still can  in other languages,

"Of marriageable age" probably beats "husbandripe" from Thomas Phaer's 1588 translation, though I guess the latter is as literal as can be! :)
